# Force ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler for a given path in Spring Security 5 (Webflux)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have two paths `/foo` and `/bar`. For `/foo` I have a custom authentication mechanism that I use. On `/bar` I have `Basic` authentication.

This setup works fine except one case. When I do not pass the `AUTHORIZATION` header in `/foo` then Basic auth kicks in instead of `MyAuthenticationFailureHandler`

Is there a way to set `MyAuthenticationFailureHandler` for a given path? Or maybe I messed up something with `SecurityWebFiltersOrder`?

My full security config:

```
bean<MyReactiveUserDetailsService>()
bean<MyReactiveAuthenticationManager>()
bean {
    ref<ServerHttpSecurity>()
        .securityMatcher {
            if (it.request.path.value().contains("/bar")) {
                ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match()
            } else {
                ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch()
            }
        }
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers("/bar/**")
        .hasRole("ADMIN")
        .anyExchange().permitAll()
        .and()
        .build()
}

bean {
    ref<ServerHttpSecurity>()
        .securityMatcher {
            if (it.request.path.value().contains("/bar")) {
                ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.notMatch()
            } else {
                ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match()
            }
        }
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .formLogin().disable()
        .csrf().disable()
        .logout().disable()
        .authorizeExchange()
        .pathMatchers(
            HttpMethod.POST,
            "/foo/**"
        ).hasRole(
            "ABRACADABRA"
        )
        .anyExchange().permitAll()
        .and()
        .addFilterAt(
            authenticationWebFilter(ref(), ref()),
            SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION
        )
        .build()
}
}

private fun authenticationWebFilter(
    reactiveAuthenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager,
    objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) =
    AuthenticationWebFilter(reactiveAuthenticationManager).apply {
        setServerAuthenticationConverter(MyAuthenticationConverter())
        setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(
            ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(
                HttpMethod.POST,
               "/foo/**"
            )
        )
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(MyAuthenticationFailureHandler(objectMapper))
    }

class MyAuthenticationConverter : ServerAuthenticationConverter {
    override fun convert(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Authentication> {
        val authHeader: String? = exchange.request.headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)
        // ... 
        return when {
            isValid(authHeader, ...) -> {
                Mono.just(
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, credentials)
                )
            }
            else -> Mono.empty()
        }
    }
}

class MyAuthenticationFailureHandler(private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper) : ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler {
    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
        webFilterExchange: WebFilterExchange,
        exception: AuthenticationException?
    ): Mono<Void> {
        val response = webFilterExchange.exchange.response
        response.apply {
            statusCode = HttpStatus.OK
            headers.contentType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
            headers.set(HttpHeaders.WARNING, """199 warning "Invalid token"""")
        }

        return response.writeWith(
            Flux.just(
                DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(
                    objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(
                        MyDto(
                            // ...
                        ).toSettingResponse()
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AuthenticationWebFilter` to set custom `ServerAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            AuthenticationWebFilter authenticationWebFilter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);
            authenticationWebFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(myAuthenticationFailureHandler) 
     return http.authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/user/signup")
                    .permitAll().pathMatchers("/user/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
                    .addFilterAt(authenticationWebFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                    .httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
                    .formLogin().disable()
                    .logout().disable()
                    .build();
        }
```